# Abusing a login form that doesn't have CSRF tokens?

Tags: authentication, security, csrf, csrf-token

I can't get my head round how a CSRF attack would work with a login form that doesn't use CSRF tokens.

This is how the process has been described to me:

1. The victim user logs in to a website that has a login page without CSRF tokens.
2. The attacker creates a web page that contains a hidden login form that targets the login page of the victim's website.
3. The attacker tricks the victim into visiting the web page containing the hidden login form, perhaps by sending the victim a phishing email or by injecting the page into a legitimate website.
4. When the victim visits the web page, the hidden login form is automatically submitted to the victim's website using the victim's session cookies, without their knowledge or consent.
5. The victim's browser sends the login request to the victim's website, and the website logs the victim in, allowing the attacker to gain unauthorized access to the victim's account.

But I don't understand how steps 4 and 5 can happen.

Regarding step 4: the attacker doesn't have the login credentials, so they can't submit a form with login details. So that rules that out? The only other option is a user has an authentication cookie set, which the form sends, **thus logging the user in. But that doesn't get the attacker anywhere?**

To do anything useful, the attacker needs to perform an additional state-changing request after logging in. And that's where CSRF tokens come in, in my mind: once logged in, use CSRF tokens to prevent state-changing requests being made via CSRF.

**So what's the point in CSRF for login forms? If CSRF tokens are being used for the rest of the application?** I.e. what harm could be done, with a CSRF attack on a login form, if the rest of the site uses CSRF tokens, but the login form doesn't?

Last question: **how would CSRF tokens for a login form be generated? And couldn't they be forged?** Like this: the attacker visits the login form, gets a CSRF token, and then sends that token with the forged request they're making the user do. **How would the victim web app know that the CSRF token wasn't obtained by the user, but by the attacker, and the attacker made the user send it?**

As I understand it, CSRF tokens are generated and associated with a user or a session. And an action is only permitted if the CSRF token passed back matches one that was generated for that logged-in user. Therefore attackers can't get hold of a valid token to make a CSRF attack.

I'm so confused!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSRF protection for login forms are useful without also using a phishing attack. They are relevant *after* a user logs in, in cases where there are forms that act on a user's behalf. But once you tricked a user to give their username and password to an attacker's domain, you don't really *need* CSRF to cause damage anyway.

A password is *also* a secret, just like the CSRF token is. At most you might be able to log a different user in for which you already have a username and password.

Personally I wouldn't even generate a session cookie until after a user has logged in, so there's no concept of a session.

I don't think there's anything wrong with just adding CSRF tokens to any form though, because it means that you don't really have to think about whether it's useful or not.